# Synchronous display of multiple worlds in the drawing layer of Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

As shown in the figure, when I zoom in and out to see multiple worlds or constantly move to the right, I want to achieve synchronized display of the marker layer in multiple worlds. How can I achieve this?

```js
  L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
  const LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
      shadowUrl: getAssetsFile("leaf-shadow.png"),
      iconSize: [38, 95],
      shadowSize: [50, 64],
      iconAnchor: [22, 94],
      shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
      popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    },
  });

  const greenIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: getAssetsFile("leaf-green.png") });
  const redIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: getAssetsFile("leaf-red.png") });
  const orangeIcon = new LeafIcon({
    iconUrl: getAssetsFile("leaf-orange.png"),
  });

  const mGreen = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], { icon: greenIcon })
    .bindPopup("I am a green leaf.")
    .addTo(map);
  const mRed = L.marker([61.495, -10.083], { icon: redIcon })
    .bindPopup("I am a red leaf.")
    .addTo(map);
  const mOrange = L.marker([71.49, -20.1], { icon: orangeIcon })
    .bindPopup("I am an orange leaf.")
    .addTo(map);
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820724/how-to-display-leaflet-markers-near-the-180-meridian and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532496/wrapping-lines-polygons-across-the-antimeridian-in-leaflet-js